# Octave imread function

Tags: octave

I installed latest Octave on Ubuntu 14.04 machine. However, when I tried to run imread command, it showed the following error message:

```
octave:12> imread('newfile.png')
error: imread: invalid image file: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/3.8.1/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/__magick_read__.oct: failed to load: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/3.8.1/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/__magick_read__.oct: undefined symbol: _ZN6Magick5ColorC1Ehhh
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/image/private/__imread__.m at line 181, column 7
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/image/private/imageIO.m at line 66, column 26
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/image/imread.m at line 107, column 30
```

Can someone please suggest how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please install ImageMagick from Ubuntu repositories and try it again to see if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

Following these steps worked for me [Author: Christoffer Cronström (hymyly)]:

Install the dev packages needed to build octave.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
```

Get the official source package. Do this in a clean directory, because it will get polluted.

```
cd ~/some/suitable/directory
apt-get source octave
```

Build it. This took roughly an hour for me.

```
cd octave-3.8.2
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Either run it from the build directory:

```
./run-octave
```

...or **most preferably** install it over the official octave:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg --install octave_3.8.2-4_amd64.deb
```

From: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave/+bug/1372202

Answer (score 0):

How did you instal Octave? The error suggests that you're missing GraphicsMagick C++ interface (package `libgraphicsmagick++3`) but

- if you installed Octave from Ubuntu's package manager you should not have had this problem; * if you compiled it yourself, Octave should have disabled imread completely and you'd have a very different error message.

So my guess is that you build it yourself, either with:

- your own build of GraphicsMagick++ which are not being loaded anymore, you may need to add their path to the dynamic linker load path (either on `/etc/ld.so.conf.d./graphicsmagick` or define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`);
- the libraries from the package manager which you have since accidentally removed (since you did not install Octave from the repositories, your package manager will not know that libgraphicsmagick++ is installed for a reason).

Either way, the solution is easy. Install Octave from Ubuntu's package manager. One of the main reasons package managers exist is to avoid this type of problems, i.e., missing dependencies.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem on 15.04; I installed via the package manager, libgraphicsmanager++3 is installed, and aptitude shows nothing broken :(

Comment: @PaulCrowley if you installed everything (both GraphicsMagick and Octave) via the package manager and it doesn't work, then report it to Ubuntu as a packaging bug.

Comment: Same here. Kubuntu 15.04 with octave and imagemagick installed from package manager... imread doesn't work

Comment: @Carlos yours (and @PaulCrowley) problem is a different issue from the original question. If you are using Ubuntu 15.04, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave/+bug/1372202 . Someone will need to fill a [SRU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) for it. As you are an Ubuntu user, will you do it?

Comment: Yes @carandraug I found the bug in launchpad, thanks. I would like to fill the SRU but I'm not sure how to do that... I will try. Regards!