# How can I solve in reading error of image in octave?

Tags: octave

I am using octave version 3.8 in ubuntu. when I am trying to read an image in octave by using imread command as below, I am getting error.

```
a=imread('bird_small.png')
```

The screenshot of image is attached herewith[image: imread error]

Can anyone help me to solve error?

Comment: You seem to be missing the imagemagick libraries, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` from a terminal. It would be easier if you mentioned which version of Ubuntu you have, they are not all the same!

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046327/octave-imread-function

Comment: also, you should really download the latest octave.